# YAML: can I put spaces into keys?

Tags: yaml

Is this valid YAML:

```
item:
  wooden wand:
    damage: 5
```

If not, how do I make it valid? I am trying to make `wooden wand` a single key, which has a value of an object containing the `damage`/`5` pair.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, that is valid YAML syntax**. You can check it online by going to [YAMLlint.com](http://www.yamllint.com/).

Their checker provides a UTF-8 friendly output of:

```
--- 
item: 
  ? "wooden wand"
  : 
    damage: 5
```

Comment: That output confuses me; do you mind explaining what it means?

Comment: @minseong spaces are allowed in keys, so your syntax is fine. The output above is simply a verbose way of writing the same thing.